# Operator norm on the space of bounded complex sequences convergent to 0

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

> We consider the space $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ of bounded complex sequences with supremum norm. Let $X\subset \ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ be the subspace of bounded complex sequences $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$, which converges to 0. Show that the formula $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-in}e^{-|n|}z_n$, for $(z_n)\in X$, defines a bounded linear functional on $X$. Determine the operator norm of $f$.

I don't understand, why we restrict our attention to the subspace $X$. I claim that this formula defines a bounded linear functional on whole $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$. Indeed, linearity is a simple matter to check. It is easily seen that $$|f(z)|=|\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-in}e^{-|n|}z_n|\leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |e^{-in}e^{-|n|}z_n|\leq \sup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|z_n| \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-|n|}=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}|z_n| \cdot (1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n});$$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}$ is a geometric series, hence, indeed, $(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n}) < \infty$. The above sequence of inequalities gives us that this series is well-defined on $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ and $f$ is a bounded linear functional on the same space - I dont' use anywhere the assumption that $(z_n)\in X$.

Anyway, I have the problem to determine the norm. of $f$. In the case of the whole space of bounded sequences, it is the easy exercise by using the above discussion. However, restricting to the case of $X$, I am not sure if the norm of $f$ is $(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n})$ as in $\ell_\infty(\mathbb{C})$. I suppose that the answer is negative, but I don't see another candidate for the norm under the restriction to $X$.

Comment: $X^*$ (the dual space  of $X$) is $l_1(\Bbb C)$, the space of  complex sequences $(y_n)_n$ such that $\|(y_n)_n\|=\sum_n|y_n|<\infty,$ where if $x=(x_n)_n$ and $y=(y_n)_n$ then $y(x)=\sum_n y_nx_n.$ But $X^*$ is a (small) proper subset of the dual space of $l_{\infty}(\Bbb C).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for $f$ does define a continuous linear functional on $\ell_{\infty}(\mathbb C)$ .

Note that $|f(z)| \leq \sum e^{-|n|}$ if $\|z\| \leq 1$. Now let $N$ be any positive integer and define $z_n=e^{in}$ if $|n| \leq N$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $(z_n) \in X$, $\|z\| \leq 1$  and $f(z)=\sum\limits_{|n| \leq N} e^{-|n|}$. Hence $\|f\| \geq \sum\limits_{|n| \leq N} e^{-|n|}$ for each $N$ proving that $\|f\|=\sum_n e^{-|n|}$.